# Why is it slow and stay "starting" in chrome download when export csv using express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, express

I'm using express to export csv and download in chrome. I'm sure the data has been fetched from mongodb readable stream and csv file can be downloaded with sporadic "Network Error" error. But the Chrome download status stayed "starting..." for a long time. The size of dataset is around 1000000.

[image: Chrome stayed "starting..."]

“即将开始下载...” means "starting...".

the server is deployed in AWS Singapore and I'm in China. Will it be just a network problem or something else ?

express 4.13.3
mongodb 3.2.1
mongoose 4.3.6

```js
// the variable 'stream' is a mongodb readable stream
stream.on('data', data => {
    let finalData = processData(data);
    let _data = JsonToArray(finalData, fields).join(',');
    console.log("Data:", _data.toString());
    res.write(_data + '\n');
});

stream.on('error', err => {
    res.end(err.message || err);
    logger.error("Export Failed:", err.message || err);
});

stream.on('end', () => {
     logger.info("Export finished after:", (new Date).getTime() - start, "ms");
     res.end();
});
```

The record has been fetched out from mongodb quickly, I think the chrome should start the download rather than "starting..."

Comment: Have you tried with VPN open?

Comment: @shaochuancs yep, with vpn open, in the router.